# Can Rails controller fix array format

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Noob to Rubes. I have an array which I built in a js file that I am inserting into a text area. This works fine, but when I submit my form the array looks like this ["68\r\n67\r\n66"].
I just want the song list array (see below controller) to look like [68,67,66]

```
  <%= form_tag(song_lists_path, multipart: true, role: 'form') do  %>
    <div class="form-group" >
      <%= label_tag 'songs', 'Add Songs'%>
      <%= text_area_tag 'songs' %>
    </div>
  <%= button_tag 'upload songs', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

And my controller code:

```
  my_songs = Array.new()
  puts "without items #{my_songs}"
  song_list = my_songs.push(params[:songs])
  puts "This is my array #{my_songs}"
```

if you want to know how I'm building array and inserting it in .js file:

```
currentVal = addedSongs.join("\n"); 
$('#songs').val(currentVal);
```

Comment: "how I'm building array" - no, you're not building an array. You're building a string. And the controller gets a string with newlines in it. So you have to do the reverse of that `join`. When looking through documentation on String class, can you spot a method that does that, the opposite of `join`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `String#split` which will break the String on space/new-line characters and give an array

```
  params[:songs] #=> "68\r\n67\r\n66"
  song_list = params[:songs].split
  #=> ["68", "67", "66"]
```

If you need in number, this will break down the array and convert each entry in integer:

```
  song_list = params[:songs].split.map(&:to_i)
  #=> [68, 67, 66]
```

Comment: Yes! The later was perfect. Thank you so much!